# Multilevel login codeigniter not success to redirect

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My database:

[image]

this is my controller

```
class Account extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('m_login'); 
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function user() {
        $data['login'] = $this->m_login->login();
        redirect('home/index');
    }
}
```

this is my model

```
<?php
class M_login extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login() {
        $username = $this->input->POST('username', TRUE);
        $password = md5($this->input->POST('password', TRUE));
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * from registrasi where username='$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1 ");
        return $data->row();
    }
}
```

i create a new controller for redirect user to different function

```
public function index() {
    switch ($this->session->userdata('level')) {
        case 'dosen':
            redirect('baprps/input_bap');
            break;
        case 'dosen koordinator':
            redirect('baprps/grafik');
            break;
        case 'dekanat':
            redirect('baprps/grafik');
            break;
        case 'mahasiswa':
            redirect('baprps/verif_bap');
            break;
        default:
            redirect('account/login');
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

when i run it, no error but why function index always going to default and redirect to ('account/login');  ?? need some help thanks..

Comment: you can achieve this with from both ways check answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look in your code. You have close your class at here.

```
class M_login extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login() {
        $username = $this->input->POST('username', TRUE);
        $password = md5($this->input->POST('password', TRUE));
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * from registrasi where username='$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1 ");
        return $data->row();
    }
}
```

But still you are trying to close after public function index() function, Please correct your code, then try again.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thats not a model, that is a new controller for redirect user to different function, but i dont know its wrong? @Manoj Sharma

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you forgot to set the session index 'level', so please edit the Account controller as follows:

```
class Account extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('m_login'); 
        }

        public function login() {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }

        public function user() {
           $data['login'] = $this->m_login->login();
           $this->session->set_userdata('level',$data['login']['level']); 
           redirect('home/index');
        }
    }
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...I think you not need to make a new controller...

Controller:

```
<?php

class Account extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('m_login'); 
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function user() {
        $this->m_login->login();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php 
class M_login extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login() {
        $username = $this->input->POST('username', TRUE);
        $password = md5($this->input->POST('password', TRUE));
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * from registrasi where username='$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1 ");

        if ($data->num_rows() > 0) 
        {

        $result = $data->row();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata('level',$result->level);

        $this->baprps();
        }
        else
        {
           redirect('home/index');
        }

    }


public function baprps() {
    switch ($this->session->userdata('level')) {
        case 'dosen':
            redirect('baprps/input_bap');
            break;
        case 'dosen koordinator':
            redirect('baprps/grafik');
            break;
        case 'dekanat':
            redirect('baprps/grafik');
            break;
        case 'mahasiswa':
            redirect('baprps/verif_bap');
            break;
        default:
            redirect('account/login');
            break;
    }
}

}
```

OR

if you want to make a seperate controller

Change in controller to

```
 public function user() {
        $data['login'] = $this->m_login->login();
        redirect('home/index');
    }
```

TO

```
 public function user() {
        $data = $this->m_login->login();
         $this->load->library('session');
         $this->session->set_userdata('level',$data->level);
        redirect('home/index');
}
```

Comment: i tried both, but still not redirect to other page @Hikmat Sijapati